# N is transitive

Tags: set-theory

I've just proved, correctly I believe, that if $X$ is inductive then so is $\{x\in X: x\subset X\}$.  So Jech says, this implies $N=\bigcap \{x:x \text{ is inductive}\}$ is transitive (Although are we allowed to define sets in that way?  Wasn't the point of having very restrictive set construction rules to avoid Russell's Paradox, so technically shouldn't we always have a larger set over which we quantify when defining sets like this?  Anyway this isn't really my question here.).

Getting back to my question, if we want to prove this, we take $x\in N$ and try to show $x\subset N$.  Since $N$ is inductive there is some inductive set $x\in Z$ and therefore $\{z\in Z: z\subset Z\}=Z'$ is inductive and so $x\in N\subset Z'$ so $x\subset Z$.  Is the following argument style correct:  If $Z$ is any inductive set such that $x\in Z$ then $x\subset Z$ therefore $x\subset N$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a set $z$ is transitive if $x\in y\in z \Rightarrow x\in z$.